# Copying an array to Range.Value2 SafeArray.pvData successful, but Excel fails to update

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

**EDIT**

Indeed, there is no direct way of editing the range values in memory.
Thanks @AndASM for the detailed answer and Carl; good hunch, it was spot-on. I must have been too tangled in all the reversing at that moment, forgetting `Value2` is just a property.

Meanwhile, I delved a bit deeper with some other tests and debugging with OllyDbg and found a few interesting things:

1. Cells are arranged in 16 x 1024 areas. The structure holding the
   areas may very well be the worksheet, but I can't confirm yet;
2. Each time the `Value` property is invoked, absolute sheet
   offsets (row, column) are used to find the corresponding area and
   then for some indexing inside the area to get the actual value;
3. A 2D SAFEARRAY of type VARIANT is created;
4. Values are not retrieved in a contiguous block, but individually.
   This means that each "point" in a range (row,col) is sent to the
   indexing procedure to return a value (variant, obviously) for its
   corresponding SAFEARRAY element;
5. As a consequence of the above, each time you retrieve a value via
   `Range.Value2(row,col)`, the whole process is reiterated for all the
   values in the range. Imagine the performance hit if you do this
   multiple times inside a procedure or, even worse, inside a loop.
   Just don't; you're better off creating a copy of `Value2` and
   addressing it via indexing;
6. Last, yet not least, the distribution of values inside
   `SAFEARRAY.pvData` is column-based `(col,row)`, not row-based, which
   may be found counter-intuitive and at odds with the VBA indexing
   mode, which is `(row,col)`. This may come in handy if you need
   accessing pvData directly in memory and keeping dimension coherence.
   As an example, a range like the one below

   ```
       1, 2, 3, 4  
       5, 6, 7, 8
   ```

   would be stored in `pvData` in the following order:

   ```
       1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8
   ```

I hope the above helps.
To sum up, in absence of any such exported function in Excel, the best way around is creating a copy of `Value2`, sorting / manipulating it towards the desired outcome and assigning it back to the range property.

---

I have recently finished a variation of QuickSort and intend to implement in for Excel. The algorithm is effective and would really bring value as an add-in, if not for the extra time spent on putting the array values into the range. Transposing only works for less than 65537, while the 'paste variant-array to range takes too long on large sorts.

So, I wrote a few procedures that would allow copying the 2D values from the range into a 1D array (1D is needed for sorting) and (after the sorting is done) putting them back, all based on SAFEARRAY and MemCopy(RtlMoveMemory) and, alternately, WriteProcessMemory.

All works well, as far as memory operations are concerned:
 - the range values are copied to the array (from one SafeArray.pvData to the other);
 - the array values (after running the sorting algo) are successfully copied to the Range.Value2 SafeArray.pvData.

Still, the range does not update, as it seems to flip back to the old values (more on that in the code below).
Why would "Range.Value2 = SomeOther2dArray" work and not modifying the data directly in memory? I have a feeling I am missing something here. Is a formula sort / update needed, as well?

Here is the main procedure:

```
    Public Sub XLSORT_Array2()
    With Application
        screenUpdateState = .ScreenUpdating
        statusBarState = .DisplayStatusBar
        calcState = .Calculation
        eventsState = .EnableEvents

        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim rngSort As Range
    Dim arrSort() As Variant
    Dim arrTemp As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dblTime As Double
    Dim dblInitTime As Double: dblInitTime = Timer

    Set rngSort = Selection

    If Not rngSort Is Nothing Then
        If rngSort.Cells.Count > 1 And rngSort.Areas.Count = 1 Then
            dblTime = Timer
            ReDim arrSort(1 To rngSort.Cells.Count)
            Debug.Print Timer - dblTime & vbTab & "(Redim)"

            'just testing Excel memory location
            'Debug.Print VarPtr(rngSort.Value2(1, 1))

            dblTime = Timer
            SA_Duplicate arrSort, rngSort.Value2
            Debug.Print Timer - dblTime & vbTab & "(Copy)"

            dblTime = Timer
            SORTVAR_QSWrapper arrSort, 1, rngSort.Cells.Count
            Debug.Print Timer - dblTime & vbTab & "(Sort)"

            'this would be the fastest method
            'variants are copied to memory
            'yet the range does not update with the new values
            SA_Duplicate rngSort.Value2, arrSort

            'dblTime = Timer
            'looping = too slow
            'For i = 1 To rngSort.Cells.Count
            '    rngSort.Cells(i).Value = arrSort(i)
            'Next

            'this works, but it's too slow, as well
            'If rngSort.Cells.Count > 65536 Then
            '    ReDim arrTemp(LBound(rngSort.Value2, 1) To UBound(rngSort.Value2, 1), LBound(rngSort.Value2, 2) To UBound(rngSort.Value2, 2))
            '    SA_Duplicate arrTemp, arrSort
            '    rngSort.Value2 = arrTemp
            'Else
            '    rngSort.Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrSort)
            '    Debug.Print "Transposed"
            'End If
            'Debug.Print Timer - dblTime & vbTab & "(Paste)"
        End If

    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState
        .DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
        .Calculation = calcState
        .EnableEvents = eventsState
    End With

    Debug.Print VarPtr(rngSort.Value2(1, 1)) & vbTab & Mem_ReadHex(ByVal VarPtr(rngSort.Value2(1, 1)), rngSort.Cells.Count * 16)
    Set rngSort = Nothing
    Debug.Print Timer - dblInitTime & vbTab & "(Total Time)" & vbNewLine
End Sub
```

Let's say the values in the range are 4, 3, 2, and 1.
Before `SA_Duplicate arrSort, rngSort.Value2` the memory reads:

```
130836704   05000000 00000000 00000000 00001040 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000840 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 05000000 00000000 00000000 0000F03F 
129997032   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

where `130836704` is `Range.Value2 SafeArray.pvData` and  `129997032` is `SortArray SafeArray.pvData`. Each 16-byte batch represents the variant actual data, as read from memory (no LE translation, just in hex), with the first 2 bytes indicating the VarType. In this case, vbDouble.

After the copy, as expected, the memory reads:

```
130836704   05000000 00000000 00000000 00001040 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000840 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 05000000 00000000 00000000 0000F03F 
129997032   05000000 00000000 00000000 00001040 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000840 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 05000000 00000000 00000000 0000F03F
```

After the sort is complete, the SortArray SafeArray.pvData reads:

```
129997032   05000000 00000000 00000000 0000F03F 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000840 05000000 00000000 00000000 00001040
```

After executing `SA_Duplicate rngSort.Value2, arrSort`, the memory shows that the Range.Value2 SafeArray.pvData has been updated:

```
129997032   05000000 00000000 00000000 0000F03F 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000840 05000000 00000000 00000000 00001040
130836704   05000000 00000000 00000000 0000F03F 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000840 05000000 00000000 00000000 00001040
```

All looking fine so far, except that `Debug.Print VarPtr(rngSort.Value2(1, 1)) & vbTab & Mem_ReadHex[...]` shows that the values flipped back to the initial order:

```
130836704   05000000 00000000 00000000 00001040 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000840 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 05000000 00000000 00000000 0000F03F
```

Please share any thoughts or methods you found effective. Any help is appreciated. It's frustrating having to wait for Excel about 4 seconds ( sorting 1,000,000 + cells), when even the most challenging sort takes less than that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it might be insightful to know what SA_Duplicate does, but since just assigning it's result down the road to range.Value2 just works, I assume the new data is correct?  So I suspect Excel internally keeps it's data in some other structure than a safearray, and the .Value/.Value2 properties are just shells that performs the translation; this would mean that direct memory manipulation of the variant these properties return is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you didn't provide a working implementation of several vital parts, especially `SA_Duplicate`, so this is mostly guess work. But, I think the answer is likely quite simple.

`Range.Value2` is a property, not a variable. So behind the scenes it is actually two functions, lets call them `Range.let_Value2` and `Range.get_Value2`.

That said, how do you expect the call `SA_Duplicate rngSort.Value2, arrSort` to work? Because what I see is `SA_Duplicate rngSort.get_Value2, arrSort`. I would assume that `rngSort.get_Value2` is creating a new SafeArray, then copying the data from Excel's internal data structures into that SafeArray. If I'm correct, you're then writing your data to a temporary buffer that VBA later discards and Excel has already forgotten about.

You need to use `rngSort.let_Value2 arrSort` which is usually called as `rngSort.Value2 = arrSort`.

As a side note, if `get_Value2` allocates a new array as I think it does, both the `SA_Duplicate` calls are unnecessary and you might be able to sort the returned array in place. Do remember to pass it to `let_Value2` by assigning the array variable back to the property when you are done.